# Authoritative server based on cloud technologies (couchdb or similar)

Tags: couchdb, cloud, document-based-database

For a few days I've been thinking about creating new game of mine using CouchDB which I'm pretty familiar with, but the problem is - I need some computation or logic done on the server side (for example updating objects not related to any player, or changing some world parameters and what not). As far as I know CouchDB and similar technologies transfer all server logic (except for maps and privileges) on front end, but could something like this be done server side? Or, could I create some sort of a bridge that would communicate with players on one side and with some document based server on the other?

Has anyone had similar issues/ideas?

Regards, V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a server process listening for database/document/view updates and react to changes in your world accordingly. **The [changes feed](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/changes.html) is your friend**. It has an http interface, decouples your logic and there are libraries for a lot of languages.

With couchdb's [external processes](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/externals.html), you can even make couchdb start and monitor your process.

Comment: That's so freaking awesome! Thanks pal :)